# Плавная графика в C# (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, разработка-игр, graphics

Пишу свой аналог игры osu!Catch the beat. Суть игры в том, что нужно ловить падающие объекты (ну для наглядности лучше загуглить игру). Графику отрисовываю на PictureBox. Есть список объектов (ну которые нужно ловить) и в событии таймера перемещаю их так:

```
foreach(fruit fr in f) //fruit - это класс того самого объекта
// f - список объектов
{
     fr.move();
     fr.draw(ref g);
     //g - это Graphics, созданный из PictureBox
}
```

Функции move() и draw() выглядят так:

```
public void move()
{
     p.Y += speed;
     //где p - это Point, задающий положение объекта
}
public void draw(ref Graphics g)
{
     g.DrawImage(image, p);
     //image - картинка объекта (находится в данных класса)
}
```

Проблема вот в чем. Интервал в таймере стоит 1ms. Если выставлять медленную скорость(конкретней - переменную speed ~ 20-30) - да, будет плавно. Но если поставить её больше (скажем 100) - то понятное дело плавность исчезнет, поскольку перемещение за раз происходит аж на 100 пикселей.

И вот как добиться нужной скорости, при этом не теряя плавность?

Comment: 1ms в таймере, это 1000 fps получается? зачем столько? что бы добиться максимально красивой плавности, нужно реализовать motion blur эффект.

Comment: Конечно же, там нет столько. Если поставить, скажем 50ms, (ну и в соотвствующей пропорции увеличить speed), то будет ещё хуже

Comment: Я боюсь, что при слишком малых интервалах таймера ваша программа начинает работать некорректно, так как реальный интервал больше, чем вы ожидаете. Нужно не полагаться на точность таймера (довольно низкую в случае WinForms) при вычислении координат, а измерять реально прошедшее время через Environment.TickCount

Comment: Ну допустим время я буду считать через Environment.TickCount, а отрисовывать мне как, все так же через событие timer?

Comment: Вам надо сначала определиться, какой скорости движения вы хотите достичь (в пикселях/ мс). 100 пикс./мс - нереально, так как при этом вся высота монитора, скажем 1000 пикс., будет проходится за 0,01 с, меньшее периода перерисовки изображения. Даже 10 пикс./мс уже довольно быстро. Потом определиться с периодом таймера (1 мс - слишком мало, я бы взял 10 мс). На основе этих величин уже можно посчитать скорость в пикс. на тик таймера (вашу speed). Так возможно и замерять время не придется, если параметры подобрать нормальные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендации по правильной реализации движущейся графики в WinForms таковы.

1. Определиться с оптимальным периодом перерисовки. Все зависит от ситуации, но меньше 10 мс для стандартных таймеров он точно не должен быть. Затем соответственно определиться, какое расстояние в пикселях объект должен проходить за этот период для получения желаемого эффекта (назовем `pix_per_tick`)
2. Вместо PictureBox рисовать в чем-то полегче, например Panel.
3. В обработчике таймера поместить код движения и обновления panel

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   p.Y -= pix_per_tick;            
   panel1.Refresh();
}
```

4. В обработчике OnPaint поместить код рисования
5. Включить двойную буферизацию на уровне ОС, добавив в код формы следующее:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
       var cp = base.CreateParams;
       cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;    // WS_EX_COMPOSITED
       return cp;
    }
}
```

Comment: После замены PictureBox на Panel результат значительно лучше. Единственное, раньше я рисовал сначала на промежуточном Bitmap, а потом присваивал его PictureBox.Image (ну да, это в принципе и есть двойная буферизация). Но вот ваш код для двойной буферизации у меня не особо сработал (если быть точней, то стало мигать ещё сильней). Можно поинтересоваться, что такое 0x02000000? Если это, допустим, код какого-либо цвета, то у меня фон черный

Comment: `panel1.Refresh();` - лучше собственную процедуру рисования сразу вывывать. При Refresh будет мерцание.

Comment: @Qwertiy Чтобы вызывать свою процедуру по таймеру, в ней нужно реализовать стирание изображения предыдущего кадра (иначе от падающего шарика шлейф будет оставаться). Да так можно сделать, но это сложнее, а мерцание можно уменьшить включением двойной буферизации через стиль окна

Comment: @9Pasha Это константа стиля окна WS_EX_COMPOSITED из заголовочных файлов Windows SDK. Этот стиль включает двойную буферизацию средствами ОС для окна и всех его дочерних окон. Не знаю почему у вас не сработало. Вы как получаете объект Graphics? Его надо брать из аргументов события Paint, чтобы это работало

Comment: @VadimTagil, вроде даже если Paint будет полностью затирать всю уобласть, это будет смотретья лучше, чем вызов Refresh. Ну и да, двойную буферизацию надо включить :)

Comment: @VadimTagil, разобрался. Результат именно тот, как я хотел. Спасибо, что уделили мне время

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, что за PictureBox такой, но в играх так уж сложилось, что перемещение осуществляется по обычной физической формуле:

S = v * t,
где:
S - расстояние, которое пройдёт объект
v - его скорость в пикселях в секунду (в данной случае)
t - прошедшее время.

Чтобы объекты двигались плавно, их надо двигать каждый кадр на S, подставляя вместо t время, прошедшее с предыдущего кадра.
В коде это может выглядеть так:

```
// вызывается постоянно, например - каждый раз, когда отрисовывается форма (OnDraw, OnRender или что-то такое)
public void move(float deltaTime)
{
p.Y += speed * deltaTime;
}
```

Вот и всё. Никаких motionBlur'ов (лезть в шейдеры, когда прогаешь под WinForms? странно), обычное движение. А привязывать движение к фиксированному фпс очень плохо: фпс никогда не будет точной мерой того, сколько прошло времени.

В вашем решении speed - не скорость в привычном понимании, а количество пикселей, на которое смещается объект за 1 тик таймера - 1 мс. Поэтому у вас возникает проблема "не могу добиться нужной скорости": потому что вы оперируете не скоростью. Нужна скорость 500 пикс/сек? Отлично, смещайте каждый кадр объект на (500 * времени_прошло_с_прошлого_кадра_в_секундах) пикселей.
Ещё замечание: не очень здорово привязывать перемещение на событие таймера, т. к. он может срабатывать либо реже, чем отрисовывается игра, либо чаще - оба случая плохи, т. к. на разных компьютерах игра будет ощущаться абсолютно по-разному, а подобная зависимость - зло.

Comment: А к чему можно привязать перемещение? (ну т.е. к какому событию или ещё к чему?)

Comment: Небольшое отступление.
Вообще в играх уже устоявшимся шаблоном можно считать использование метода Update. Этот метод должен вызываться каждый кадр, а в нём уже происходит вся логика: проверка столкновений, свои вычисления и т. д. Утрированно, но для примера подойдёт.

А касательно вашего вопроса: привязать перемещение можно, например, к событию отрисовки формы. Называться оно должно как-нибудь вроде OnDraw, OnRender, OnPaint. Точно не помню, т. к. с WinForms почти не работал. Вот в таком событии и вызывайте свой Update - ну или в вашем случае: move, draw и т. д.

Comment: П. С. Вообще могу порекомендовать книгу "Шаблоны игрового программирования": 
https://www.gitbook.com/book/likerrr/gameprogrammingpatterns/details

Comment: Ну у меня был вариант отрисовывать через OnPaint. Но просто если я буду вызавать фунцию Draw() внутри неё, то она собой повлечет обработку события OnPaint, что в принципе является бесконечным циклом, в следствии чего игра виснет

Comment: Тут вряд ли могу чем-то помочь, т. к. никогда не отрисовывал графику таким образом. Просто поделился тем, что знаю. Удачи;)

Comment: @9Pasha move() привязать к таймеру, а Draw() - к OnPaint, тогда ничего виснуть не будет.  kakeru походу путает с DirectX, в winforms его поход вряд ли применим